# Problem with remote connection to my sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, remote-connection

I wanted to use my PC as SQL Server and connect to it from my notebook but I can't connect to it via public IP adress. Later i will need to create connection string to my c# application but for now I'm just using SSMS for testing. Few details about my configuration :

- I'm allowing remote connection to this server.
- Server authentication is in mixed mode.
- SQL Server browser is on.
- TCP/IP protocol is enable.
- I'm forwarding port 1433 on my router.
- I turned off my firewall and AV for testing.
- I can ping my PC by it's public IP adress.
- I can connect to SQL Server by it's local IP adress...

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a named instance of SQL Server, then you must also forward SQL Server Browser port ( by default UDP 1434 )

Comment: I forwarded 1434 port too. Still can't connect via public IP.